# using biblatex with res.cls

Tags: biblatex, resume

I am having a problem getting `biblatex` to work with [`res.cls`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/res)

I have successfully used biblatex using the `article` class to create a nice bibliography the way I want it to look.  However, when I try and use it within the class `res`, I get a

```
! Package keyval Error: revisers undefined.
```

message.

In fact, this message appears simply by adding

```
\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
```

in the preamble.

Any ideas?

Here is a minimal example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[overlapped,line,letterpaper]{res}

\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}
\fi

\hypersetup{
  letterpaper,
  colorlinks,
  urlcolor=black,
  pdfpagemode=none,
  pdftitle={Curriculum Vitae},
  pdfauthor={Daniel L. Zelazo},
  pdfcreator={$ $Id: cv-us.tex,v 1.28 2006/12/12 22:53:52 jrblevin Exp $ $},
  pdfsubject={Curriculum Vitae},
  pdfkeywords={networked dynamic systems control optimization}
}

%%===========================================================================%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\addbibresource{dz_pubs_2011.bib}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$-$}
%%===========================================================================%%

\begin{document}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document Specific Customizations

% Make lists without bullets and with no indentation
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}

% Use large bold font for printed name at top of pages
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\large\textbf}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{Daniel L. Zelazo}

\begin{resume}

\hspace{-37pt}\begin{ncolumn}{2}
  {\bf Research Associate \& Lecturer} & \\ 
  {\small Institute for Systems Theory \& Automatic Control} &\hfill {\small Phone: +49 711 685 67747} \\
  {\small University of Stuttgart }     &\hfill {\small Fax: +49 711 685 67735} \\
  {\small Pfaffenwaldring 9  }        &\hfill {\small {\tt daniel.zelazo@ist.uni-stuttgart.de}} \\
 {\small  70550 Stuttgart, Germany   }          &\hfill {\small {\tt \verb+http://www.ist.uni-stuttgart.de/~zelazo/+} }\end{ncolumn}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{\bf {\large Education}}
\begin{ncolumn}{1}
  {\bf University of Washington} \hfill  Seattle, WA         \\
  {\bf PhD} \hfill September 2004 - September 2009 \\ 
  \\
  Department of Aeronautics \& Astronautics Engineering  \\
  Thesis: \emph{Graph-theoretic Methods for the Analysis and} \\\emph{Synthesis of Networked Dynamic Systems} \\
  Advisor:  Prof. Mehran Mesbahi      \\                 
\end{ncolumn}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------


\section{\bf {\large Publications \& Patents}}
See attached list.

\nocite{*}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Letters},keyword=letter, prefixnumbers={L}]

\end{resume}

\end{document}

%%===========================================================================%%
```

for the dz_pubs_2011.bib file, the following should be sufficient:

```
@misc{Holland2011,
author = {Holland, Alex and Zelazo, Daniel},
title = {{Sensitivity Analysis in Control Versus Biology}},
howpublished = {Letter to the Editor of PLoS Biology regarding the 2009 PLoS Biol 7(1) e10000015 and e1000021 articles},
year = {2011},
keywords={letter}
}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem: I see no error if I use `res.cls` from CTAN and load `biblatex`.

Comment: I added a MWE; if you comment out the biblatex usepackage and all the other lines related to biblatex, it compiles fine.  Otherwise I get the keyval error

Comment: Your non-minimal example works fine for me if I remove `\nofiles` from `res.cls`.

Comment: @1yen: You loaded `hyperref` twice. `hyperref` should normally load after all other packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should avoid using such old and outdated classes.

The problem based on the macro `\nofiles` which is used by `res.cls`. This macro tell LaTeX no needing of `.aux` files. To work with bibliographies you need an `aux` file.

I recommend to change the document class. Otherwise you must edit the document class and comment the command `\nofiles`.

I used the following example for testing:

```
\listfiles
%\let\nofiles\relax
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{ctan} and \cite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks Marco, I already have \nofiles commented out, with no change.  Also, how do I discover if a class is "old" or "outdated"?

Comment: @1yen: First of all the class has no documentation. That is a bad style. Second: The class isn't included in TeX Live or MikTeX. You must install manually. For testing I used the linked `res.cls`. I tried a very simple example. I will add the example to my answer.

Comment: thanks for clarifying...even with your example I am getting the same keyval error.  My res.cls has \nofiles commented out.  Can you suggest are better cv class file with good example templates?

Comment: You can use [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) or [`europecv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/europecv).

Comment: @1yen: Is this question answered for you?

Comment: yes and no...thanks for the info, but I am still not able to get your code to work either, must be something else wrong for me...